# Is there any commentary on the Battle of 10 kings mentioned in the Rig Veda?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, war

Is there any commentary on the [Battle of 10 kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ten_Kings) mentioned in the Rig Veda Samhita?

Like for example a commentary by [Sayanacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayana)?

Wikipedia says about him:

> His commentary on the Rigveda was translated from Sanskrit to English
>   by Max Müller

Where can I read this commentary?

Answer (score 1):

Please do not read the one by Max Mueller, since he is from colonial era whence they had only one objective = show Vedic literature to be external to India.

Instead, the best commentary I read on the battle of 10 kings in Rig Veda (as well as the much earlier battle of 5 kings in Rig Veda) is by Dr. David Frawley.

It is called "*Gods, Sages and Kings: Vedic Secrets of Ancient Civilization*". I bought it and read it and I liked the part where he gave sanskrit slokas with english translation to prove his point (that Vedic culture was native to the land of seven rivers between Indus & BhramaPutra rivers).

You can get it from here (I am NOT an affiliate or a seller on Amazon, and I am NOT affiliated with seller at this link or with Dr. David Frawley): [https://www.amazon.com/Gods-Sages-Kings-Secrets-Civilization-ebook/dp/B002OB4RZM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002OB4RZM)

If you live in the west, you will find a copy of it in your local public library, please search and you can borrow it from your local public library as well.

You can also read my post on Quora.com on this topic here:
https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-reason-for-Battle-of-the-Ten-Kings/answer/Jay-Sekhar-2

Answer (score 1):

Many scholars wrote their own articles on [Daśarājñá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ten_Kings) war, on the hymn  [RV 7.18](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07018.htm) & [7.33](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07033.htm).

However, Shaunaka's [Bṛhaddevatā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%B9%9Bhaddevat%C4%81) (400 BCE), did not contain any reference to this war.  The extracts of pages from Bṛhaddevatā, containing reference to RV 7.18 and RV 7.33 have been pasted below:

[image]

[image]

Hence, I am presuming that Daśarājñá war that was inferred to have occurred by many scholars, might not have occurred, but those mantras might be referring to some deep spiritual aspects, composed in a cryptic manner,