# Does any Purana describe Dasharajna war?

Tags: vedas, puranas, war, itihasa

I read about the [Dasharajna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ten_Kings) war in Vedas. But, in Vedas the description of the war is very less. Does any other scripture like Itihasa or purana describes about Dasharajna war?

Comment: please provide Sanskrit term (transliteration) for Dasharjana

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any commentary on the Battle of 10 kings mentioned in the Rig Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31754/is-there-any-commentary-on-the-battle-of-10-kings-mentioned-in-the-rig-veda)