# Did the Battle of the Ten Kings really occur?

Tags: puranas, rig-veda, upanishads, brahmanas

**There is already a question existing - [Timeline of the battle of the ten kings in the Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13747/3869).  However, there are no answers posted yet and my question is different.**

---

It was mentioned in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Ten_Kings) that The **Battle of the Ten Kings** (Sanskrit: दाशराज्ञ युद्ध, romanized: Dāśarājñá yuddhá) is a battle alluded to in the Rigveda (Book 7, hymns 18, 33 and 83.4–8), the ancient Indian sacred collection of Vedic Sanskrit hymns.

It was also mentioned that the battle took place during the middle or main Rigvedic period, near the Ravi River in Punjab. It was a battle between the Puru Vedic Aryan tribal kingdoms of the Bharatas, allied with other tribes of the north west India, and the Trtsu-Bharata (Puru) king Sudas, who defeats other Vedic tribes.

---

However, mention of the **Battle of the Ten Kings** is missing in  [Bṛhaddevatā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%B9%9Bhaddevat%C4%81), but many a translator of Rig Veda, including Stephanie W. Jamison and Joel P. Brereton, mentioned it as occurred.

My question is whether **Battle of the Ten Kings** (दाशराज्ञ युद्ध) really occurred ?

Was it mentioned in brAhmanas or aranyakas or upanishads or any commentary on Rig Veda/***any other literary work***  by Indian authors of past era(prior to 18th centuary) ?

If so, please provide references.

Comment: IMHO, "My question is whether Battle of the Ten Kings (दाशराज्ञ युद्ध) **really** occurred ?" -- it's opinion based.. and if u remove really then u Q itself has answer..

Comment: I requested for quoting references from brAhmanas, aranyakas,etc,.  Hence, it cannot be opinion based @YDS

Comment: then ur Q should be in that way..

Comment: You can suggest the change in the question, so that I can edit it @YDS

Comment: @srimannarayanakv "Cowardice indeed" concern the [code of conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct) while posting comments.

Comment: @Pandya: What more can I do?  When the some of the members opt for closing a question with mala fide intentions, without mentioning the reasons thereon, what can I do?

Comment: @Pandya:  When moderators are remaining biased what more can I do?

Comment: @Pandya: Except posting a warning messages to members like me, what are the moderators doing, except taking sides with a group of members?  Go ahead and impose a ban on me

Comment: You could post a friendly comment e.g "I see close votes scientific speculation but I don't want scientific speculation, I am looking for historical events";; btw, title looks opinion based.

Comment: @Pandya: As usual, a biased reply.  I am not expecting a better reply from your end.

Comment: Post related to your question "is it mentioned in any other scripture" : [Does any Purana describe Dasharajna war?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40111/277).